# Unable to start Adobe AEM

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

I am unable to start AEM. I am constantly getting error:

```
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: org.osgi.dto; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework; version=1.8.0, org.osgi.framework.dto; version=1.8.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.service; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.launch; version=1.2.0, org.osgi.framework.namespace; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.startlevel; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.startlevel.dto; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.wiring; version=1.2.0, org.osgi.framework.wiring.dto; version=1.2.0, org.osgi.resource; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.resource.dto; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.service.packageadmin; version=1.2.0, org.osgi.service.resolver; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.service.startlevel; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.service.url; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.util.tracker; version=1.5.1, org.apache.sling.launchpad.api;version=1.2.0,   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.)
ERROR: Bundle installation from slinginstall:F:\AEM\crx-quickstart\launchpad\startup\1\org.apache.sling.fragment.ws-1.0.2.jar failed (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.)
ERROR: Bundle installation from slinginstall:F:\AEM\crx-quickstart\launchpad\startup\1\org.apache.sling.fragment.xml-1.0.2.jar failed (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.)
04.10.2017 23:36:59.418



*INFO * [main] Startup completed
```

I am using AEM-6.2-quickstart.jar

this is line causing error

`osgi-core-packages=org.osgi.dto; version\=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework; version\=1.8.0, org.osgi.framework.dto; version\=1.8.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle; version\=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver; version\=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.service; version\=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving; version\=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.launch; version\=1.2.0, org.osgi.framework.namespace; version\=1.1.0, org.osgi.framework.startlevel; version\=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.startlevel.dto; version\=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.wiring; version\=1.2.0, org.osgi.framework.wiring.dto; version\=1.2.0, org.osgi.resource; version\=1.0.0, org.osgi.resource.dto; version\=1.0.0, org.osgi.service.packageadmin; version\=1.2.0, org.osgi.service.resolver; version\=1.0.0, org.osgi.service.startlevel; version\=1.1.0, org.osgi.service.url; version\=1.0.0`

Comment: Delete your already existing `crx-quickstart` folder and Rename your jar file to aem-author-4502.jar. Otherwise, please provide more information on how you are starting aem. double click or command line?

Comment: was the aem instance working before? Or was this a new instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a "," at the end of thew system bundle package exports property. Try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please rename the jar file similar to

> aem-author-p8502.jar

this and try to start?